# VS Code File change indicator

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure when it stopped but VS Code is not displaying little red circle on file explorer icon when you change files.

Can you please help? 
I re-installed VS code but didnt help.

[No indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmwvq.png)

Comment: Can you please put more details with screenshot?

Comment: I updated my original post with the link to screenshot. As I you see there is no indicator on file icon (it works fine on source control icon) .No mater how many file I update or change there is no indication that files were updated.

Answer (score 5):

You must have the *Auto Save* feature enabled, if enabled then every change will be saved after a delay hence no need to display an indicator.

You can disable the *Auto Save* feature by unticking `File` \ `Auto Save`.